# Excel Copy Hyperlinks Formula

Tags: excel, hyperlink, formula

I have a problem with excel hyperlinks-formula:

I did an index search on a sheet B where i found results from sheet A.
The results found in sheet A are hyperlinks on sheet A.

Now my Problem is, that i want to have the results found also as hyperlinks which link me to the same sheets (C-Z) like sheet A.

I tried Hyperlink(Index(....)), but it won'T work.

Any ideas?

Comment: to be a bit more precise:
Coloumn B on sheet A has hyperlinks to all other sheets on my workbook.

i did a index-search on sheet B which refers to sheet A (="Plaza Übersicht") and looks like this:
=IF(ROWS('Plaza Übersicht'!$1:10)>COUNTIF('Plaza Übersicht'!$I$5:'Plaza Übersicht'!$I108;E$4);"";INDEX('Plaza Übersicht'!$B$1:'Plaza Übersicht'!$B108;SMALL(IF('Plaza Übersicht'!$I$5:'Plaza Übersicht'!$I$99=E$4;ROW($5:$99));ROW('Plaza Übersicht'!$B10))))

I want to inserst a Hyperlink-feature to this formula to get the result-hyperlinks.
Problem: Cannot open specified file

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Select your result in sheet B, by selecting the top cell and doing cntr+shift+Down.

Step2: Copy and paste it as values in a adjacent column (Say column B) by doing Alt+E+S+V.

Step3: In a column adjacent to the result column from Step2 in your sheet B, type in the formula =HYPERLINK(B1) (replace B1 with whatever cell you copied your values to in Step2).

Step4: Copy the formula down by dragging the corner of the cell from Step3.

Step5: You are done.